# In the new Theme Customizer API, how to send a value from the front back to the admin panel?

Tags: customization, api, theme-customizer

I'm digging a bit into the new Theme Customizer API, in particular into the javascript one, and what I find is delighting.
I've managed to add my own custom parameters, and I also have the javascript part to update those parameters live into the preview.

However, I would like to go a bit further : I need to place a point on an absolute position over a background image, and then record the position back into the database. Here is a screenshot.
[image]
I can move the point thanks to jQuery draggable plugin, but I don't know how to send the resulting position back to the customizer.

Here is my code so far :

`functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'customize_register', 'minisites_customize_register' );
function minisites_customize_register($wp_customize){
    // gestion du placement des points
    class Minisites_Customize_Page_Control extends WP_Customize_Control {

        public function render_content() {
            ?>
            <label>
                <span class="customize-control-title"><?php echo esc_html( $this->label ); ?></span>
                Points position
                <input <?php $this->link(); ?> value="<?php echo $this->value()?>">
            </label>
            <?php
        }
    }
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'points', array(
        'transport' => 'postMessage'
    ) );
    $wp_customize->add_control( new Minisites_Customize_Page_Control( $wp_customize, 'points', array(
        'label'      => __( 'Lier les pages', 'minisites' ),
        'section'    => 'background_image',
        'settings'   => 'points',
    ) ) );

}
```

`customize-theme.js`:

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {

    var points;
    wp.customize( 'points', function( value ) {
        points = value;
        value.bind( function( newval ) {
            // this code is called when the value change
            console.log('position change', newval);
        });
    } );

    $('.point').draggable({ 
        drag: function(event, ui){
            // update the position value
            point.set(ui.position);
        }
    });

});
```

The javascript `points.set()` call **does** update the position value (I get the correct info in the console) but **can't** update the input element located in the theme customizer itself.

I had a look at the `api.Value` Class (witch is the class of my `points` variable) in `wp-includes/js/customize-base.js`. What I would need is to get the instance of the corresponding `api.Element`, and call its `update` method. But I cannot figure out from where I can get this.

Comment: You'll need to save this using the methods described under [tag:ajax].

Comment: @kaiser: thanks for your suggestion. But in this case, every point move will be instantly published to the frontend. Is there a way to save it only to the theme customizer, and then save it in the database when the user clicks the "save & publish" button ?

Comment: Hold it in a javascript var?

Comment: I already have it in a javascript var. But then, how do I get this value (which reside in the theme iframe, not in the admin area customizer) when the user clicks the "save & publish" button ?

Comment: Use a global var that you localized using `wp_localize_script()`. Then save the data using AJAX. See [tag:ajax] questions/answers.

Comment: @FabienQuatravaux - how are you doing on this?  I need a similar functionality and have some questions - is there a good way to contact you without starting a long discussion on your question here?

Comment: @Brian : Please check [my github profile](https://github.com/Fab1en), where I have added my email address.

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to solve my issue, but not in the most elegant way : polling. I would still be interested in more elegant solution !

The main issue I have is that the point move is done in the iframe containing the site preview, whereas the theme customizer form inputs are in the main document. So I need a way to pass variable from the iframe to the main document.

Inside the iframe :

```
// update point global var
$('.point').draggable({ 
    drag: function(event, ui){
        // update the position value
        var ref = 'id'+$(this).attr('data-id');
        points[ref].top = ui.position.top;
        points[ref].left = ui.position.left;   
    }
});
```

In the theme customizer :

```
setInterval(function(){
    if(frames.length) {
        var from = $('#customize-points').val();
        var to = JSON.stringify(frames[0].points);

        // use theme customizer API in order to enable the save button
        if(from != to) $('#customize-points').val(to).change();
    }
}, 500);
```

I have also added a system to calculate the points position relative to the background image, but that's not the subject here.

I know that the theme customizer generate events targetting the preview iframe to enable the theme author to live update the preview, but I can't find how to do the other way round : generate an event from the preview to the theme customizer.

You can see the result online here: [focus.tv5monde.com](http://focus.tv5monde.com), even if you cannot access to the backend.

Comment: @Brian: does this answer will helps you ?

Comment: it helps, but I guess I'm not sure how the positioning is happening on http://focus.tv5monde.com/languedelautre/ ... did you have to set the points position manually or is it happening via the jQuery draggable function updating the "Points position" input field?